# How to lowercase the words in the front end products page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

so I have made the **products** in the **admin page** of **magento 2** like below picture.
[image]

but on the frontend it look like this[image]

so my question is how to make Mm lowercase into mm in the products page on the frontend. any idea?

Comment: add css h1.page-title { text-transform: none; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css

```
.catalog-product-view h1.page-title {
   text-transform: none;
}
```